# Can't Fetch Only One CloudKit RecordType

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

This app uses CloudKit and I sync the data to Core Data locally. I believe I have the basics working with one exception. The following code checks for changes in CloudKit and allows me to save to Core Data but I have been unable to limit the downloaded changes to one single recordType (I have two recordTypes, "Patient" and "PatientList"). I thought that CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions() should allow filtering by recordType but everything I have read and tried only allows filtering by desiredKeys across all recordTypes, which of course is not useful for my purpose. I can limit the Core Data saves by recordType but that seems to be the wrong approach.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 8.3.3 iOS10 Swift 3

```
func checkUpdates() {

    let operation = CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: changeToken)
    let myZone : CKRecordZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "myPatientZone")

    var zonesIDs : [CKRecordZoneID] = []

    //you ONLY want changes from myPatientZone
    //you ONLY allow one custom zone and you ONLY share myPatientZone
    operation.recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock = { (zoneID) in
        if zoneID == myZone.zoneID {
            zonesIDs.append(zoneID)
        }//if
    }//recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock

    operation.changeTokenUpdatedBlock = { (token) in
        self.changeToken = token
    }

    operation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = { (token, more, error) in
        if error == nil && !zonesIDs.isEmpty {
            self.changeToken = token
            let options = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions()
            options.previousServerChangeToken = self.fetchChangeToken
            let fetchOperation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: zonesIDs, optionsByRecordZoneID: [zonesIDs[0] : options])
            fetchOperation.recordChangedBlock = { (record) in

                let recordName = record.recordID.recordName

                let request : NSFetchRequest<Patient> = Patient.fetchRequest()
                request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordName = %@", recordName)

                do {
                    let result = try self.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)

                    //if the record is not in the local core data
                    if result.isEmpty {
                        let patient = Patient(context: self.persistentContainer.viewContext)
                        patient.recordName = recordName
                        patient.firstName = record.object(forKey: "firstname") as? String
                        //all the other fields here...

                        try self.persistentContainer.viewContext.save()

                    } else {

                        //if the record is in core data but has been updated
                        let patient = result[0]

                        //patient.recordName - don't change

                        patient.firstName = record.object(forKey: "firstname") as? 
                        //all the other fields

                    }//if result.isEmpty

                } catch {
                    //add the CRS custom error handler
                    print("Error")
                }//do catch
            }//fetchOperation

            //fetchOperation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { (recordID, recordType) in

            //fetchOperation.recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock = { (zoneID, token, data) in


    database.add(operation)

}//checkUpdates
```

Comment: Im a bit confused by your question. Can u explain your goal or question on a more general level?

Comment: When you use the CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation for syncing with CloudKit you get changes for ALL recordTypes. So if you have 10 recordTypes but only want to update one, you have to do another parse locally along with the logic to store it locally. I want to filter the fetch for only one recordType.

Comment: Why not just query for one recordtype, then you can easily modify info from the one record type